# Why does c# delegate calls accept function names as argument?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand delegates. when I run the following code:

```
public delegate void DelegateType1();

public static void callDelegate1(DelegateType1 callback) {
    callback();
}

void start() {
    callDelegate1(runMe);
}

void runMe() {
    Debug.Log("Why?");
}
```

It outputs 'Why?'.

My question is: If *CallDelegate1* takes an argument of type *DelegateType1*, why does it also accept a function name as argument? Also, is this a bad practice? Every tutorial I've seen online stores the function name in a variable of type *DelegateType1*.

Comment: I think the question is analogous to asking why you can call a function declared `f(int i)` with an argument of `1`. An `int`   variable represents a reference to an int value; a delegate "[represents references to methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)". A function name is the delegate literal, like `1` is an int literal

Comment: exactly @PeterA.Schneider

Comment: C# Specification: **6.6 Method group conversions** An implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from a method group (§7.1) to a compatible delegate type.

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing:

> ```
> void f(long l) { }
> void g() { f(1); }
> ```
>
> My question is: if `f` takes an argument of type `long`, why does it also accept an `int` as argument?

Because there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`.

> My question is: If *CallDelegate1* takes an argument of type *DelegateType1*, why does it also accept a function name as argument?

Because there is an implicit conversion from a method group to a delegate type.

> Also, is this a bad practice? Every tutorial I've seen online stores the function name in a variable of type *DelegateType1*.

The most explicit form is

```
void start() {
    DelegateType1 runMeDelegate = new DelegateType1(runMe);
    callDelegate1(runMeDelegate);
}
```

You can make it less explicit by writing it as a conversion:

```
void start() {
    DelegateType1 runMeDelegate = (DelegateType1) runMe;
    callDelegate1(runMeDelegate);
}
```

You can make it even less explicit by making the conversion implicit:

```
void start() {
    DelegateType1 runMeDelegate = runMe;
    callDelegate1(runMeDelegate);
}
```

And finally, you can get rid of the variable entirely:

```
void start() {
    callDelegate1(runMe);
}
```

They are all perfectly fine and all do the same thing. The first form is something that code generators typically use, because explicit construction of a delegate type is something that's most widely supported in different languages. The last form is something that programmers tend to write when it's obvious to someone with sufficient C# experience what's going on there.

Tutorials are not focused on programmers with sufficient C# experience, so to make it clearer what's going on, they may choose to use one of the more verbose forms. There is nothing wrong with sticking with that form if it helps you understand, but there is equally nothing wrong with using the shorter form.